# What is the advantage and disadvantage of adding an extension path while linking pages

Tags: php

I realized my links still work if i didnt add .php to my page links...

For example:

```
<?php 
<a href="property.php">view property</a>
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
<a href="property">view property</a>
?>
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of adding .php or not adding .php

Comment: It's more pretty and user-friendly - the end-user doesn't care what extension the file you're presenting the page through is. If you are able to do that, then you either have a folder by that name, or you have some `.htaccess` magic which masks the extension.

Comment: What's your server environment here?

Comment: Do you mean that if you save a file called `foo.php` in say a document root, you can still access it via `example.com/foo`?

Comment: @Progrock i use wamp server on dreamweaver... "Do you mean that if you save a file called foo.php in say a document root, you can still access it via example.com/foo"  well i i haven't tried it yet but i am pretty sure it should be accessable... What actually happened was i was linking my head navigation in my website and forgot to add .php to the file and when i was cross checking my work, i realized it worked.

Comment: @peter i surely need it thanks!

Comment: @Quirel i understand you, thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to clarify if you can access a file that ends in a php extension without entering the extension.  That's how I initially read your question.  But it sounds as if files that have no .php extension are still being parsed as php by apache.  I would think that is non-standard behaviour.  So I'd be interested to see your apache configuration (please detail your WAMP version and any config changes).